# jQuery check is element in first three or last three rows of table

Tags: jquery, html-table

I would like to adjust button dropdown/dropup menu to the position on table, for this I have to determine in which row the button is in.

Normally it should drop down but if the button is in the last three rows of the table it should be dropped *up*. Here is working example:

```
if (/* button is on the three last table rows */) {
    $('.dropdown-toggle').parent().removeClass("dropdown");
    $('.dropdown-toggle').parent().addClass("dropup");
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bh9kxe9w/1/

Comment: [What have you tried so far?](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/) Where is your code?

Comment: good, you have the logic now , try some code ...

Answer (score 0):

You can't add an id to your button?
In order to improve the table's style you can put the top button inside of  and the bottom button in

Comment: I can't add id to button.

Comment: Try this    
`if($('tr:first', this)) 
{ do something if first line }
else
{ do something if last }`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you tried so far, but [first-selector](https://api.jquery.com/first-selector/) and [last-selector](https://api.jquery.com/last-selector/) will work for you.

And if you are using loops then try,

```
var len =$('table tr').length;
$('table tr').each(function(i,v){
    if(i==0){
         // your code for first row drop down
    }

    if(i==(len-1)){ // starting index 0
        // your last row code
    }    
});
```